# Trouble Binding to WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid that I wish to bind to the following data model, but I can't seem to get it correct.  Initially, the List that I am binding to will be empty, and I want to give the user the ability to enter in the information. So I define the data grid as such:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"/>
```

My model class is as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public string Details
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} was born on {1} and this is a long description of the person.", this.Name, this.Birthday.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }
}

public class Group : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._name)
            {
                this.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ID { get { return this._id; } }
    public List<User> GroupUsers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

What I would want to do is bind on the Group class, but only to the GroupUsers value.  How do I do that?  Do I have my User's property GroupUsers defined correctly for TwoWay binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `User` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `GroupUsers` property should be an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So do I follow the INotifyPropertyChange pattern like for the Name property?

Comment: Yes. For each public property in the User class.

Comment: Thanks for that, It appears to be binding correctly now!  Thank you for your help.